# Aligning columns in Wordpress sub menu

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, drop-down-menu, formatting

I am trying to fix an issue with the menu for a Wordpress site that I help to develop. The theme that the site uses is Illdy Child. The issue is that the first column of each sub-menu is slightly off from the other columns, and the first column also has a completely empty space. [Here is a screenshot of what the menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lCml.png).

Below is the CSS pertaining to the sub-menu that I put in the "Additional CSS" section for the Wordpress site.

```css
.header-button-one {
    font-size: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    background: none !important;
    background-image: url("wp-content/themes/illdy/images/down_arrow.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    margin-top: 50px !important;
}

.markets-served-item img{
    height:auto !important;
}

.markup-format table tbody tr td {
    border-right: #eee !important;
}

.markup-format table{border-right: 1px solid #000;}

.bottom-header h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.col-md-8 col-sm-8 .markup-format a { text-decoration: underline; }

.blog-post h2 a {text-decoration: underline;}

.blog-post hr {border-top: 1px solid black;}

.page-numbers{list-style: none;}

.page-numbers li{display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;}

.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ED1C24 !important;
    border-color: #ED1C24 !important;
}

#breadcrumbs span span:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ED1C24 !important;
    border-color: #ED1C24 !important; 
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ED1C24 0,#ED1C24 100%) !important;
}

graybg{background-color:#EDEDED !important;}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu { 
    
    min-width: 700px !important;
    justify-items: left;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu { 
    display: block;
    /*display: grid; */
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    column-fill: auto;
    column-gap: balance;
    min-width: 700px !important;
    justify-items: left;
}



.page-id-2191 li {
    list-style: none !important;
}

header#header {
    background-attachment: scroll !important;
}

.page-id-1893 tbody tr {font-size: 18px !important; font-weight:400; !important}

#blog .blog-post .blog-post-meta{display:none;}

.blog-post-related-articles .related-article-title:after {
    content: "Latest Articles";
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
}
.blog-post-related-articles .related-article-title {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The HTML code for the menu generally looks like this:

```html
<nav class="responsive-menu">
        <ul> 
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                <a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/request-for-quote">Request for Quote</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-45"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/about">About</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2566"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/news-and-events">News and Events</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7349"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/about/lens-manufacturing-process">Lens Manufacturing Process</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3050"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/about/fai-policy">FAI Policy</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1334"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/about/warranty">Warranty</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2416"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/about/careers">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1052"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions">Solutions</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1222"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics">Custom Optics</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6415"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/optical-coatings">Optical Coatings</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2535"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/optical-lenses">Optical Lenses</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3204"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/aspheric-lens">Aspheric Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5896"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/achromatic-lenses">Achromatic Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5879"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/acylindrical-lenses">Acylindrical Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4474"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/biconvex-convex-lenses">Biconvex / Double Convex Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3210"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/high-precision-spherical-lenses">Spherical Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3551"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/cylindrical-lens">Cylindrical Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3211"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/high-quality-plano-convex-lenses">Plano-Convex Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3209"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/plano-concave-lenses">Plano-Concave Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3212"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/germanium-lenses">Germanium Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5064"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/uv-lenses">UV Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5479"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/ball-lenses">Ball Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3365"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/infrared-germanium-aspheric-lenses">Infrared Germanium Aspheric Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3206"><a href="https://staging.avantierinc.com/solutions/custom-optics/microlens-array">Microlens Array</a></li>
```

What I'm expecting is for each row and column to be properly aligned. Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If we don't see your HTML code I don't think we can understand the problem. Please share the HTML code of the menu

Comment: Okay! I added a link to the HTML code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.